# Quarkus Interceptor

Tags: java, quarkus

Im trying to intercept all calls and verify if a customer exists in the db.  I get an error of

You have attempted to perform a blocking operation on a IO thread. This is not allowed, as blocking the IO thread will cause major performance issues with your application.

Quarkus version 2.6.3

```
import io.quarkus.vertx.web.RouteFilter;
@Provider
public class Filter {
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    @RouteFilter(100)
    public void filter(RoutingContext routingContext) {
        String id =routingContext.request().getHeader("id");
        Cutomer c =customerRepository.findById(id);
        if(c!=null) {
            // throw error
        }
        /**
         * Tried
         * Uni.createFrom().item(()->customerRepository.findById(id))
         * .runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool());
         */
        routingContext.next();
        
    }
}**strong text**
```

Comment: As described in quarkus doc (https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#request-or-response-filters), add `@Blocking` should resolve the issue

Comment: @Blocking still throws the same error

Comment: https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#request-or-response-filters discusses ServerRequestFilter and you are using a vertx RouteFilter. Perhaps you should switch filter type and use @ServerRequestFilter(nonBlocking=false)?